# Delegating something to the OS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I was wondering if it is possible to tell the iphone operating system to lauch my application when I enter a particular region...If it is how can I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This will happen automatically for region monitoring - Once your application has registered for region monitoring (while it was running) and then gets suspended or stopped, and then if the region is crossed even when you app is not running the app is re-launched in the background to handle that event, from there you can post local notifications etc to alert the user and bring the app to foreground if the user is interested.
See reference to the Apple [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

Answer (score 0):

No, your application can't launch itself for any reason.

You can, however, use background location and background local notifications to alert the user and allow them to **opt** to open your app.

Comment: Not true, region monitoring can auto launch your app.

Comment: No, it can popup a notification, but the user can choose not to launch the app. It'll remain stuck in the background if the user says no.

Comment: what if I want to launch a custom aler message can I do it instead of lauching my app?

Comment: @ceejayoz: you're right but the app does get launched into the background and has a chance to run in the background so it can do processing, just can't get into the foreground without user interaction.

Comment: I interpreted "launch my application" in the question to mean that the application should automatically come to the foreground.